# .I have a query that why doesn't print(emp.__repr__()) give error for passing 3 arguments ved, root, 5000 as __repr__() has only self as argument

Tags: python

```
class Employee:

       def init(self, first,  let,  pay) :
              self. first=first
              self. last=last
              self. email=first+'.'+last+'@gmail.com'

       def__repr__(self):
              return '{} ,self.first'.format('hi') 
emp=Employee('ved', 'root', 5000)

print(emp.__repr__())
```

Comment: You seem to be missing a space.

Comment: There is a space after and before __repr__ .Sorry typing error.

Comment: and it's  __init__.

Comment: Then [edit] to give a [mcve] that actually recreates your problem. Why do you *expect* an error?

Comment: Please fix your code to a [MCVE] format.

Comment: Also you had `let` instead of `last` as an argument of `Employee` class, it'll fail at `self.last = last`.  Under `def __repr__(self)` you probably also meant to print the *value* of `self.first`, not the literal string "self.first"? You should also put a curly bracket and put `self.first` under `format()`.

Comment: Please edit your title. It is offputtingly unreadable.